# Rally Java API to pull just Team members from Project

Tags: java, api, project, rally

I would like to write a Java API to retrieve just the team members for each project in Rally and push to db. Is there any query which could help me with this request?

The project could be identified by naming convention, as our workspace has hierarchical based projects where only last tier of hierarchy holds the team members list.

Please do mail me if you need further details

Thanks

Sree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code example that returns team members of a project:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String username = "user@co.com";
        String password = "secret";
        String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129"; 
        String applicationName = "RESTExample get team members";

        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 
        System.out.println(restApi.getWsapiVersion()); 

        try{
             QueryRequest projectRequest = new QueryRequest("Project");
             projectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "TeamMembers"));
             projectRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
             projectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", "Company X"));

             QueryResponse projectQueryResponse = restApi.query(projectRequest);
             int count = projectQueryResponse.getResults().size();
             System.out.println(count);
             if(count > 0){
                 JsonObject projectObject = projectQueryResponse.getResults().get(count-1).getAsJsonObject();
                 int numberOfTeamMembers = projectObject.getAsJsonObject("TeamMembers").get("Count").getAsInt();
                 if(numberOfTeamMembers > 0) {
                        QueryRequest teamRequest = new QueryRequest(projectObject.getAsJsonObject("TeamMembers"));
                        JsonArray teammates = restApi.query(teamRequest).getResults();
                        for (int j=0;j<numberOfTeamMembers;j++){
                            System.out.println(teammates.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("_refObjectName").getAsString());
                        }
                    }
             }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally{
            restApi.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for your valuable reply.

Comment: Nick, I'm getting error error: constructor QueryRequest in class QueryRequest cannot be applied to given types;
                        QueryRequest teamRequest = new QueryRequest(projectObject.getAsJsonObject("TeamMembers"));
  required: String
  found: JsonObject
  reason: actual argument JsonObject cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion.How do I solve this error?

Comment: I have the latest rally-rest-api-2.0.4.jar in the path. What version do you have? By default this jar will use WSAPI v2.0. I don't set it in the code, but I println restApi.getWsapiVersion(). It should print v2.0. This code works in my environment. If you did not make changes to the code, apart from workspace OID, project name and credentials, chances are this is jar version related.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it worked I replaced older version of the jar file and it displayed results. However I want Every Project's Team member.  There are nearly 350 project with 10 members each. This program shows only one Projects' Team member list. I added this condition to filter the project projectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "contains", "DT-")); As our project where team members are associated starts with DT-. Do I need to For loop for projects too? Please advise. Thanks for your Prompt reply.

Comment: Yes. I modified the code to loop over multiple results returned from query `new QueryFilter("Name", "contains", "Team")` GetTeamMembers.java is in this github repo: https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps

Comment: it worked like charm. Thanks a lot. One last question, why the count of my query projectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "contains", "DT-")); always shows 200. As there are more than 400 DT- Projects. will it be restirction in output window in my Netbeans or something I need to  add in the Query? Please advise

Comment: Yes I found the solution for it too  int queryLimit = 4000;
   projectRequest.setLimit(queryLimit); it gave me the actual results. Thanks Nick Cheers